# send sms from gmail using python script

Tags: python, sms, gmail

I am trying to work for sending sms from gmail using python.
I have tried many solutions but it didnt worked.
I tried to use libgmail but seems to be deprecated. Even I am not able to find how to send sms from gmail to jawwal where as actually gmail sends free sms to jawwal.

My code is:

```
import libgmail
from TextMessaging import *
sender = Sender(<username>, <password>)
txtM = TextMessage(subject, body)
receiver = Receiver("<phone no>", "Jawwal")
sender.sendMessage(receiver, txtM)
```

in this, on sender it gives error as expected string or buffer
and for reciever, i dont know whats carrier for jawwal like

```
CARRIERS = {"Alltel":"alltelmessage.com",  
            "ATT":"mobile.mycingular.com",  
            "Rogers":"pcs.rogers.com",  
            "Sprint":"messaging.sprintpcs.com",  
            "tMobile":"t-mobile.net",  
            "Telus":"msg.telus.com",  
            "Verizon":"vtext.com"}
```

Kindly give me on any information how to send sms to gmail using python script.

Thanks

Comment: Post your existing code, please.

Comment: I am trying to use TextMessaging from gmail but which has already error.

Comment: Could you post your code? I don't feel like writing a whole program. If you want help, could you help us help you?

Comment: @Blender : i have posted code

Comment: on sender it gives error as expected string or buffer
and for reciever, i dont know whats carrier for jawwal like

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you would want to use one of these services:

```
[https://www.twilio.com/sms][1]

[http://www.clockworksms.com/][2]
```

They provide REST API options.

I know this is an old question, but just posting for someone searching for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

"As of April 1, 2014, sending SMS messages to phone contacts through Google Chat in Gmail was 
discontinued for all supported mobile operators."

https://support.google.com/chat/answer/112176?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I think the carrier's email address for your phone is as such:

```
jawwal.com.country_code
```

Replace `country_code` with the appropriate URL extension (`.sa`, `.lb`, etc.).

Comment: yes tried as jawwal.com.ps, jawwal.ps, noone of worked. Also TextMessaging also have the error. is there any another way of sending sms from gmail? gmail is already facilating sending smss that way. i just want to use them in python script.

Comment: yes. it says as module object is not callable after username and pwd of gmail

Comment: libgmail hasn't been maintained in quite some time and deprecated. so its not working as gmailsms also uses the libgmail